# how to upload/deploy NextJs Project to Free hosting cpanel?

Tags: react-redux, next.js

I am using a free hosting Cpanel I want to upload my Next js Project. I tried all the reference but with no hope. I executed 'next build' but no build folder is created. What do I do to make it run in server.

Answer (score 0):

You should export your build as static application and then upload via ftp in cpanel to host application.

https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export